# AngularJS MVC 4/Razor and quote delimited data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my angular application I'm using a store name in three ways:
for example:

```
SelectedStore: {{ currentStore }}
<ul>
    @foreach(var store in Model)
    {
        <li ng-hide="currentStore=='@(store.Name)'>
            <a href="#" ng-click="setCurrentStore(@(store.Id), '@(store.Name)')">
                @(Store.Name)
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

The problem is that if my store name has a ' in it then it screws this code up.  I could replace `'` with `&apos;` but then my selected store is garbled.  Is there a clean way to do this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Will the store name ever have double quotes in it?

Comment: It could have that issue as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went ahead and did an ng-init and passed in the JSON'ified model so that angular would have full control of the data in scope

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to do this is to have a code behind function to replace single quotes with escape sequences for them (`\'`).

Something like:

```
SelectedStore: {{ currentStore }}
<ul>
    @foreach(var store in Model)
    {
        <li ng-hide="currentStore=='@(escapeSingleQuotes(store.Name))'>
            <a href="#" ng-click="setCurrentStore(@(store.Id), '@(escapeSingleQuotes(store.Name))')">
                @(Store.Name)
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

This is because you are kind of working against the way that Angular prefers to work, with all data being fetched and stored on the scope by the controller, not populated in the markup by server side code.

Comment: I just went ahead and did an ng-init and passed in the JSON'ified model so that angular would have full control of the data in scope